# Using crawl rules to exclude Allitems.aspx, DispForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search-results, crawl-rules

Is anyone having any idea on how to exclude List Forms from Search result.

I tried lot many things suggested on google, but none of them seems to be working.

Comment: why don't you try exclude the list from search results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the options would be to configure properties of the Search Results web part. Specifically specify `IsDocument:"True"` property to exclude Lists pages from search results.

### How to exclude Lists pages from search results via Search Results web part

- Open search results page in Edit mode
- In the Search Results Web Part, click the Search Results Web Part
  Menu arrow, and then click Edit Web Part
- In the Web Part tool pane, in the `Search Criteria` section, click
  `Change query`
- In Property Filter, select property named `Path` and specify value
  `This site`, then click `Add property filter` button (the generated query is shown on figure below)

[image]

Alternatively you  could create a new `Result Source` and apply changes per Site, Site Collection or Tenant.

- Create a new `Result Source`. Depending on scope (Tenant, Site
  Collection, Site) go to the corresponding `Result Source` page and select a `New Result Source` link.
- Specify the following query: `{searchTerms?} IsDocument:"True"`
- Go to `Result Source` page . Select result source and click `Set as
  default` in context menu.

### References

[Configure properties of the Search Results Web Part in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549987%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Is there a way we can do this through central admin via crawl rules?

Comment: You could achieve the same results by creating a new Result Source. Please verify an updated answer.

Comment: Amit, glad this helped you :)

Comment: this was very helpful. learned a new thing today.Thanks very much @Vadim.

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure. Cause i ran in the problem when excluding allitems.aspx with crawl rules the content in the site isn't crawled anymore.

So check if everything is crawled to be sure. to exclude allitems.aspx i would add the following in the result resource: -filename:allitems.aspx